# Issue writing unit test with N-Unit and Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

Junior C#/.NET developer here and was just tasked with writing my first-ever unit test for a service method I created today. My company uses N-Unit and Rhino Mocks so I am trying to watch a Pluralsight course right now to teach myself both frameworks. Below is the method I created as well as my unit test that I attempted to write, and the error it is producing :(

Can anyone tell me what I’m doing wrong?

**Method To Be Tested:**

```
public bool shouldSubmit(long clientId)
{
    bool isEncrypted = clientFeatRepo.hasClientFeat(clientId, FeatEnum.Encrypted);

    bool isSeamless = clientFeatRepo.hasClientFeat(clientId, FeatEnum.Seamless);

    if (isEncrypted == false && isSeamless == false)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Unit Test:**

```
public void testShouldSubmit()
{

    clientFeatRepo.Stub(x => x.hasClientFeat(111, FeatEnum.NotEncrypted)).Return(false);

    clientFeatRepo.Stub(x => x.hasClientFeat(111, FeatEnum.NotSeamless)).Return(false);

    bool results = apiPackageService.shouldSubmit(111);

    mocks.ReplayAll();

    Assert.IsTrue(results);

}
```

**ERROR:**

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Previous method 'IClientFeatRepo.hasClientFeat(111, NotEncrypted);' requires a return value or an exception to throw.
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RecordMockState.AssertPreviousMethodIsClose()
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RecordMockState.MethodCall(IInvocation invocation, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.Invocation.Actions.RegularInvocation.PerformAgainst(IInvocation invocation)
   at Rhino.Mocks.Impl.RhinoInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.IClientFeatRepoProxyaa745bc909574b67a5ccce407ef647a9.IClientFeatRepo.hasClientFeat(Int64 clientId, FeatEnum featEnum)
   at MercuryUserWeb.Core.Services.ApiPackageService.shouldSubmit(Int64 clientId) in C:\Users\DFriedland\Documents\Core\Services\ApiPackageService.cs:line 190
   at MercuryUserWebTest.Core.Services.ApiPackageServiceTest.testShould() in C:\Users\DFriedland\Documents\Core\Services\ApiPackageServiceTest.cs:line 1210
```

**CORRECT TEST CODE:**

```
public void testShouldSubmit()
{

    clientFeatRepo.Stub(x => x.hasClientFeat(111, FeatEnum.NotEncrypted)).Return(false);

    clientFeatRepo.Stub(x => x.hasClientFeat(111, FeatEnum.NotSeamless)).Return(false);

    mocks.ReplayAll();

    bool results = apiPackageService.shouldSubmit(111);

    Assert.IsTrue(results);

}
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, what do you mean? Is there an error message?

Comment: Please show the entire service class that contains `shouldSubmit`. Also, show how you instantiate your service and mocks in the test.

Comment: @yelxe The service class this method belongs to is quite large (1161 lines of code) so I cannot paste that here. It is actually only one of more than 120 services in our rather large code base. The test class for this method is 1227 lines as of now. Well it is now with my test method ;)

Comment: @Bassie Yes, there is an error. Thank you for reminding me. I will post it in the OP. Sorry about that!

Comment: First, the default return value for mock methods is `default(<type>)` so you can remove the `stub` using.... second, the exception you've attached is usually raised when you don't use the `Return` method. Are you sure that you are using this method in the context of your UT?(there is a typo between your snippets....)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by removing the stub. If I do that I will get a compilation error. Can you give me an example? I am going off of the Pluralsight video and yes, I believe I am using the .Return extension method in the context of my UT.

Comment: @DeanFriedland you can remove `clientFeatRepo.Stub(x => x.hasClientFeat(111, FeatEnum.NotEncrypted)).Return(false);` + `clientFeatRepo.Stub(x => x.hasClientFeat(111, FeatEnum.NotSeamless)).Return(false);` and have receive the same result... that's what I've meant..

Comment: Not sure I understand. Those are the values I am testing. How can I omit them from the test???

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this was occurring was the placement of the         `mocks.ReplayAll();` expression. I added the correct test code to my original post. I hope this helps someone with the same issue and I thank those who tried helping.